# Fun with CSS floats

Tags: css

I have the following CSS for some DIVs,

```
#wrapper {
  width:960px; 
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#maintitle {
  width:600px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #333;
}

#sidebar {
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#rightSidebar {
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  float:right;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

I would think the #rightSidebar div would float to the very top right corner of the #wrapper div, however, it's staying below the #maintitle DIV.

The #maintitle DIV is floating to the left, would it then allow the #rightsidebar div to float to the very top right corner?

Here it is in action, http://jsfiddle.net/BdpU7/.

Comment: Please change your question title so something more fitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind? http://jsfiddle.net/BdpU7/1/

The `#rightSidebar` needs to go before `#sidebar` in the HTML, and then `#sidebar` has to have the `clear`:

```
#wrapper {
    width:960px; 
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#maintitle {
    width:600px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #333;
}

#sidebar {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#rightSidebar {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid green;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="maintitle"></div>
    <div id="rightSidebar"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```